# I want to know the number of rows stored in a block of a table stored in the tablespace

Tags: sql, oracle, admin

I used the code below to find the average number of rows stored in a block of a table.

But I want to know the average number of rows stored in a block of a table stored in a specific tablespace.

Any help on how to change the query would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT
      ROUND(AVG(CNT))
  FROM
      (SELECT
              SUBSTR(A.ROWID,10,6) ROW_NM
            , COUNT(*) CNT
         FROM [OWNER].[TABLE_NAME]
        WHERE 1=1
     GROUP BY SUBSTR(A.ROWID,10,6)
     ORDER BY 1) B;
```

Comment: Is your table partitioned? Otherwise you will end with only one tablespace...

Comment: it's mixed And in the case of a partitioned table, it is stored scattered across multiple tablespaces. shit!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to user the package [DBMS_ROWID](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/DBMS_ROWID.html#GUID-66872807-DA5F-4AD8-B447-69BCB258D69B)

Specifically the functions

```
ROWID_TO_ABSOLUTE_FNO  to get the file number that can be mapped to tablespace and

rowid_block_number  to get the block number
```

The sample query see below

```
with rid as (
select 
DBMS_ROWID.ROWID_TO_ABSOLUTE_FNO (rowid, 'OWNER','TAB') as file_no, 
dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(ROWID) block_number from tab),
rid2 as (
select 
   file_no, block_number, TABLESPACE_NAME
from rid
join dba_data_files on rid.file_no = dba_data_files.FILE_ID),
rid3 as (
select block_number, TABLESPACE_NAME, count(*) row_cnt
from rid2
group by block_number, TABLESPACE_NAME)
select TABLESPACE_NAME, round(avg(row_cnt)) avg_cnt
from rid3
group by TABLESPACE_NAME
order by 1
```

The subqueries perform

- get file number and block number for each for
- map file number to tablespace using `dba_data_files`
- calculate row count per block and tablespace
- calculate AVG row count per tablespace

You may need to adjust the paramater `ts_type_in`  of the function [ROWID_BLOCK_NUMBER](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/DBMS_ROWID.html#GUID-B191C62C-74FC-4E19-A166-2522F9936BFD) if you use *bigfile*s.

Comment: Thanks for the good tip. BIGFILE is not being used. However, in RID (first WITH clause), it seems that only one OWNER and TABLE can be specified. How can I specify multiple?